# jquery $.post rejected by server but $(form).submit() working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was trying to get data using javascript using jquery ajax or jquery post

```js
$.post("https://members.myactivesg.com/facilities/quick-booking?activity_filter=18&venue_filter=296&date_filter=Wed,%205%20Aug%202015", function(data) {
    debugger;
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    debugger;
  });
```

However, it's not working. But jquery form submission is working.

```js
    var form =
      '<form action="https://members.myactivesg.com/facilities/quick-booking" method="post" class="formfilter" id="formQuickBookSearch">' +
      '<input type="hidden" name="activity_filter" value="18">' +
      '<input type="hidden" name="venue_filter" value="296">' +
      '<input type="hidden" name="date_filter" value="Fri, 7 Aug 2015">' +
      '</form>'
    $(form).submit();
```

The server return me status code 400.

Comment: Anybody can help on this ?

Answer (score 3):

You are not making a true post in the Ajax call. You should NOT be using a query string to pass the data. Use the data parameter in jQuery's post method.

```
$.post( "https://members.myactivesg.com/facilities/quick-booking",  {"activity_filter":18, "venue_filter" : 296, "date_filter":"Wed, 5 Aug 2015"}, function(data) {
    debugger;
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    debugger;
  });
```

Comment: Guess you need to look at the server log and see what is going on. How are you triggering the Ajax call?

Comment: I've no access to the server. I fire the script in chrome console. The script is to book facility because manually booking hardly able to secure the slot.

Answer (score 1):

The URL that you;re using is an equivalent of GET request. E.g. `//site.com/?foo=bar`

[jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) uses `data` argument to pass POST values.

I recommend to use only jQuery.ajax(), because it gives you more control and understanding.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", // Request type.
  url: url, // https://members.myactivesg.com/facilities/quick-booking
  data: data, // Your values as associative array.
  success: success, // Success callback.
  dataType: dataType // Expected response type.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method, full example :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getMessageBoxData (queryType) {
    function url_redirect(options){
        var $form = $("<form />");

        $form.attr("action",options.url);
        $form.attr("method",options.method);

        for (var data in options.data)
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="'+data+'" value="'+options.data[data]+'" />');

        $("body").append($form);
        $form.submit();
    }

    $(function(){
        /*jquery statements */
        url_redirect({url: "messageBoard.php",
            method: "post",
            data: {"queryType": "select"}
        });
    });
}


</script>


<button onclick='getMessageBoxData()'>Click to getMessageBoxData</button>
```